# Web config redirects not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-config

I have been asked to set up a redirect from:

https://www.#####.co.uk/news/uk-families-have-more-money%E2%80%93butalso-more-debts/

TO

https://www.#####.co.uk/news/

I have added the following rule to my web config:

```
            <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="news/uk-families-have-more-money%E2%80%93butalso-more-debts/" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://#######.co.uk/news/"  redirectType="Permanent"  />
            </rule>
```

But it is not having any effect.

I know '%E2%80%93' for UTF8 represents '-', so I have tried substituting for that, but the rule is still not having an effect.

Any ideas? Is there anyway I can debug this?

Comment: If you edit your redirect rules in IIS manager you get a UI where you can easily test if your URL matches your rule. (With respect to the "Is there any way to debug this")